# How to Remove Id Field and Some standard field in selectOption. I am add the field through schema class in apex

Tags: apex, schema

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get('contact');
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
        String fieldLabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
        String fieldNameAPI = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getName();    
        Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
         options.add(new SelectOption(fieldNameAPI,fieldLabel)) ;  
        //options.add(new SelectOption(fieldNameAPI+' '+string.valueof(fielddataType),fieldLabel)) ;  
    }
    system.debug(':____:   '+options);
```

In this Code I am add the All field of Contact but my need is remove some field in this option

How can I remove some field in the select options in this code
like as Id, also some not writeable field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition to filter based on [`Schema.DisplayType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm) enum. Like:

```
fielddataType != Schema.DisplayType.String
```

Apex [`DescribeFieldResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) has properties which can be used for additional filtering, like `isAccessible()` in your case.

Comment: @vikasrathi if this answers your question, mark it as such :)